# Unix. Change separator between 2 specific columns that have a different separator

Tags: unix, separator

I have a huge .txt file A with 6 columns. The first 5 columns are separated by a tab, but columns 5 and 6 are separated by a white space. Some columns have missing elements. Using Unix, how can I generate another file B.txt that has columns 5 & 6 separated by a tab?

A.txt

```
1   886620  rs201016776 T   A 1:886620-TG
1   879576  rs115979567 C   T
1   886817  rs111748052;rs10465241  C   CATTTT  JHU_1.886816
1   889255  rs150003341 C   T Variant37585
1   891659  rs116557519 G   A JHU_1.891658
```

B.txt

```
1   886620  rs201016776    T    A    1:886620-TG
1   879576  rs115979567    C    T
1   886817  rs111748052;rs10465241    C    CATTTT    JHU_1.886816
1   889255  rs150003341    C    T    Variant37585
1   891659  rs116557519    G    A    JHU_1.891658
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `column -t inputFile`

```
 $ column -t A.txt > B.txt
```

If the `tabular` form using `column` doesn't work, one can be explicit about the `tab` using `awk`:

```
 $ awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7}' A.txt > B.txt
```

Comment: Thank you @iamauser, your script produces columns separated by several tabs (more than 60 white spaces) in some cases

Comment: It isn't easy to read `tab` and `whitespace` from your comment, can you make it clear with words, what happened when you ran the command ?

Comment: Hi @iamauser. I just did it.

Comment: @Lucas, it seems you have more than 6 columns in some lines, but your question says 6 ? Does your question represent part of your input data ?

Comment: Thank you very much @iamauser. The only problem with your script is that is separates lines by tabs as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with gnu sed

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]/\t/g' A.txt > B.txt
```

Comment: Wouldn’t this add a `tab` to every single `whitespace` ?

Comment: @iamauser no s=substitute. [[:blank:]]=tab or whitespace so substitute all tab or whitespace by a tab.

Comment: That's not correct. You have a `g` at the end, which will substitute for each and every whitespace with a `tab`. `[[:blank:]]` is equivalent of `[ \t]`. Try with `echo 'a b' | sed 's/[[:blank:]]/\t/g'` and add a space between `a` and `b`, try it again.

Comment: @iamauser each whitespace is replace by a tab ? if you want to get only one tab, you must use sed -E 's/([[:blank:]]{1,})/\t/g'

Comment: exactly and your answer is lacking all those you've written in your comment. OP's question to use _a_ tab between the columns, _not_ replace every whitespace by _a_ tab.

Comment: @iamauser I don't understand what you want to say, perhaps, you want to say your answer is the better ? the OP ask for The first 5 columns are separated by a tab, but columns 5 and 6 are separated by a white space. so my answer is for the question.

Comment: No, that's not what I am saying. I am saying, your solution adds more than one `tab` between column, 5 and 6.